# Selenium Grid configuration of timeouts

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid2

I'm using Selenium Grid 2.

I have a single hub and 6 nodes.
The problem I'm running into is some test fail due to unexpected javascript popups, and selenium doens't seem to be cleaning up these sessions.  When the tests finish, there are browsers still open (multiple on each test machine), and there are still IEDriverServer.exe processes running.

This is the hub.json file I'm using:

```
{
  "host": null,
  "port": 4444,
  "newSessionWaitTimeout": -1,
  "servlets" : [],
  "prioritizer": null,
  "capabilityMatcher": "org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher",
  "throwOnCapabilityNotPresent": true,
  "nodePolling": 5000,

  "cleanUpCycle": 5000,
  "timeout": 300000,
  "browserTimeout": 60000
}
```

Any additional input is appreciated...

FYI, I do have a finally block in my framework that the last thing it does is

```
driver.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

My perspective is from Java, but I would imaging the .Dispose() method would work if it did two things:

1. call driver.quit()  (not driver.close() )
2. then, set driver = null   to mark for garbage collection

To my knowledge, there is no timeout that cleans up browsers automatically in Selenium.  There are 3 different kinds of timeouts you can set on the driver but none are related to what your asking.

As a sidenote, I call driver.quit() in my "@AfterClass" annotation.  Then in each of my classes it will run multiple times through the parameterized data and then finally quit the browser.   In my "@AfterTest" annotation I do things related to prep for the final HTML report.

Comment: In C#, driver.Quit() actually calls driver.Dispose().
I was previously using Quit, but changed to Dispose before I looked up the actual code and saw it was doing the same thing.